# Apply Filtering in ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, listview

I have a ListView and I want to apply filtering functionality in it.

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="CollegeDetailsView"
    DataKeyNames="CollegeID" ItemType="CollegeDataLibrary.CollegeDetail"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false" ItemPlaceholderID="CollegeItem"
    AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true"
    SelectMethod="GetData" OnItemDataBound="CollegeDetailsView_ItemDataBound">
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        There are no entries found for Colleges
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
    <LayoutTemplate>
```

The GetData Method is:

```
public IQueryable<CollegeDataLibrary.CollegeDetail> GetData()
    {
        var context = DataOperations.GetCollegeDetails();
        return context.AsQueryable();
    }
```

I have taken the two dropdownlists in which, if user select both or single values, the listview will show the corresponding record. I have applied the following code:

```
protected void SearchField_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Created = DDLCreatedBy.SelectedItem.Value;
        string Fdp = DDLFDP.SelectedItem.Value;
        var context = DataOperations.GetFilteredData(Created, Fdp);
        CollegeDetailsView.DataSource = context.ToList();
        CollegeDetailsView.DataBind();
    }
```

The GetFilteredData method is:

```
 public List<CollegeDetail> GetFilteredData(string Created, string FDP)
    {
        using (CollegeDataEntities context = new CollegeDataEntities())
        {
            return context.CollegeDetails.Where(cs => cs.CreatedBy == Created && cs.FDP == FDP).ToList();
        }
    }
```

The context has the exact values but after binding it shows the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing that error because you are trying to bind the ListView in two ways. You are using the model binding approach in your markup and setting the `DataSource` manually in your code behind.

One thing you could try to do is remove the model binding and just stick to binding it manually. Remove the `ItemType` and `SelectMethod` and instead just call the GetData in your Page_Load or something.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CollegeDetailsView.DataSource = GetData();
    CollegeDetailsView.DataBind();
}
```

Then your other filtering should work as is, assuming the filtering is setup correctly. The other thing you could try is obviously the opposite - sticking to just model binding and removing all the manual binding. Here is an [asp.net article on model binding](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/model-binding/retrieving-data).